# Charset in an iframe

Tags: iframe, character-encoding

I have an xhtml document encoded in UTF-8. The document is dynamically loading an iframe whose content is encoded in windows-1255. The latter information is encoded in both the HTTP response header and a meta tag inside the html head. Yet the iframe is displayed in UTF-8. I encounter this behavior on both Firefox and Chrome (on a mac).

The content of the iframe itself is served by a Java servlet, which explicitly sets the HTTP Content-Type to windows-1255 (and moreover, there is a meta tag seconding that inside the html). On itself, the page displays correctly.

What am I doing wrong?